# Unbale to send a .yml file from spring boot service to fastApi python service

Tags: python, java, spring, spring-boot, fastapi

I am trying to send a .yml file from my spring boot service to my python FastApi service. but I keep getting following error.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$UnprocessableEntity: 422 : [{"detail":[{"loc":["body","files",0],"msg":"Expected UploadFile, received: <class 'str'>","type":"value_error"}]}]
```

here is the spring boot code that i am using to send the file to python service.

```
 File file2 = new File(("./src/main/resources/testcases/"+filename+".yml"));
 MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            body.add("files",file1);
            body.add("files",file2);
            body.add("message", message);

            HttpHeaders bbheaders = new HttpHeaders();
            bbheaders.set("x-api-key", x-api-key);
            bbheaders.set(StringUtils.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION, request.getHeader(StringUtils.HEADER_AUTHORIZATION));
            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> bbhttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, bbheaders);

            restTemplate.postForEntity( url, bbhttpEntity, String.class);
```

and here is the python code that is receiving the request:

```
async def upload_file(request:Request,files:List[UploadFile]= File(...),message:str=Body(...),Authorize: AuthJWT = Depends()):
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not the right way to send HttpEntity including .yaml file body.
Firstly you have to convert yaml files to json and then send json as the body of your request.
To convert that you can use:

```
String convertYamlToJson(String yaml) {
    ObjectMapper yamlReader = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    Object obj = yamlReader.readValue(yaml, Object.class);

    ObjectMapper jsonWriter = new ObjectMapper();
    return jsonWriter.writeValueAsString(obj);
}
```

Then put the String in the body.